# Calculating Chi Squared in Matlab is constant?

Tags: matlab, statistics

I've been trying to calculate the chi squared test on some lab measurements for school. for some reason, i keep getting a constant result, no matter what the ranges i'm trying to calculate over.
The function i'm trying to test, in matlab, is:

```
ev_g = @(i,b,x_i) (i.*sin(pi.*b.*x_i)./(pi.*b.*x_i)).^2
```

my input is the x_i vector, and i'm trying to find the b and i that fit the best to the measurements. the code which is malfunctioning is:

```
function [ chi2_min, b_final, i_final ] = chi2_general( func,var, guess_1,guess_2,O_i,error,limit1,limit2,step1,step2 )
i=guess_1;
chi2_min = 999999;
b_final = 0;
i_final = 0;

while i<limit1
    b=guess_2;
    while b<limit2
        chi2_temp = sum((O_i-func(var,i,b)).^2./(error.^2));
        if chi2_temp<=chi2_min
            chi2_min = chi2_temp;
            b_final = b;
            i_final = i;
        end
        b=b+step2;
    end
    i = i+step1;
end        
fprintf('%f\n%f\n%f', chi2_min, b_final, i_final);
end
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly you are trying to do with this statement:"ev_g = @(i,b,x_i) (i.*sin(pi.*b.*x_i)./(pi.*b.*x_i)).^2
;"? And which of the output arguments is constant?

Comment: That is the function handle. I have the x_i variable (something I measured), and I'm trying to find the i and b which fit the other measurements i did. Does that explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to understand where the malfunction is with knowing the parameters you are using for all function parameters, but some simple observation reviewing the code: You are defining your function with the parameters `(i,b,x_i)` and then you call it with the parameters `(var,i,b)`, which probably should be `(i,b,var)`?